# float precision in numpy arrays differ from their elements

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision

I have values of `numpy.float32` type, and a numpy array with `dtype="float32"`.

When outputting the representation of the values directly using the individual array element references, I get a difference in precision than when I output the representation of the array object itself.

The ensuing calculations are also a bit off, so the latter value seems to be the one used in consequtive vector / matrix artihmetic.

Why is there a difference, and must these precision "anomalies" be handled manually?

```
>>> a = math.pi / 2

>>> a
1.5707963267948966

>>> elementx = numpy.float32(math.cos(a))

>>> arrayx = numpy.array([elementx], dtype="float32")

>>> elementx
6.1232343e-17

>>> arrayx
array([  6.12323426e-17], dtype=float32)

>>> t = numpy.float32(3.0)

>>> t * elementx
1.8369703e-16

>>> t * arrayx
array([  1.83697028e-16], dtype=float32)
```

(Python 3.5.2, GCC 5.4.0, linux 4.4.0-21-generic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just differences in the string representation, the values are the same and calculations are not off.

```
>>> (t * elementx) == (t * arrayx)[0]
True
```

Comment: Even: `(t * elementx) == (t * arrayx)` => `array([ True], dtype=bool)` .... which actually was my question :) thanks.